# high-quality png without changing the multiple-plot appearance in R?

Tags: r, plot, png

To produce a high-quality `png` file from a plot, I usually increase the value of the `res =` argument of the `png()`. But in the following case, I have a complex **7x4** plotting platform, and changing the `res =` changes the actual appearance of the plot (e.g., plot frames look much thicker etc.).

I am wondering how I could raise the quality of the following plot while preserving its original appearance (i.e., as shown in the graphical device)?

**P.S:** I'm just trying to achieve a high-quality version of what I see in my graphical device.

```
png("Plot.png")

par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(7, 4)) 
invisible(lapply(1:28, plot, t = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n"))

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look better?

```
png("Plot.png", res = 600, width = 8, height = 7, units = "in")
par(mai = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
par(mfcol = c(7, 4), mar = rep(.1, 4), oma = rep(7, 4)) 
invisible(lapply(1:28, function(x){
    plot(rnorm(20), rnorm(20), axes = FALSE, col = sample(1:7, 1), ann = FALSE)
    box()
    }))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you can also increase width and height parameters within png. As you increase res, if you increase the width and height the relative layout will stay the same, but you'll end up with more pixels so for a given physical dimension it will be higher resolution.